# Switch image by using hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Hi there I want to ask if it is possible to have an image list and everytime I hover on one of them it will display on another div and will not disappear.

Take a look on the picture below instead of clicking the list of image I want to hover it and it will display on the bigger div and will stay there. The hovered image will replace the displayed image

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iip7.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. We don't debug images here.

Comment: Be aware that hover event handlers are not  mobile-friendly. Consider using click or something touch-capable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the large image's source to that of the hovered thumbnail.

EG:

```js
var main = document.querySelector("#main");
var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll("#thumbs img");
thumbs.forEach((thumb) => {
  thumb.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    main.src = thumb.src;
  });
});
```

```css
#wrap {
  width: 300px;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
}

#thumbs {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#thumbs img {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img id="main" src="" />
  <div id="thumbs">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the key is to use "onmouseover" in html, if u want it to change after leaving use "onmouseleave"

```js
var a = 'url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iip7.png" )';

function noone(element) {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = a;
}
```

```html
<!-- div for the main -->
<div id="div1">This statement will change</div>
<!-- div for the one of the down image, i used img not div -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iip7.png" onmouseover="noone(this) ;" alt="">
```

Comment: While you're right, this topic was well covered 20 years ago, and you shouldn't guess at a problem that's poorly presented. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

You will need JS for this. On events `onmousenter` for the thumb you get src of the thumb and change src of the target picture and `onmouseleave` you switch it back to original.

Comment: While you're right, this topic was well covered 20 years ago, and you shouldn't guess at a problem that's poorly presented. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].